# How to make a function for matching the string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python, trying to make a function for matching the strings.

```
N="TAG"
K="L"
D="E"

g4 = 'NKXD'
protein = 'MASEIHMTGPMCLIENTNGRLMANPEALKILSAITQPMVVVAIVGLYRTGKSYLMNKLAGKKKGFSLGSTVQSHTKGIWMWCVPHPKKPGHILVLLDTEGLGDVEKGDNQNDSWIFALAVLLSSTFVYNSIGTINQQAMDQLYYVTELTHRIRSKSSPDENENEVEDSADFVSFFPDFVWTLRDFSLDLEADGQPLTPDEYLTYSLKLKKGTSQKDETFNLPRLCIRKFFPKKKCFVFDRPVHRRKLAQLEKLQDEELDPEFVQQVADFCSYIFSNSKTKTLSGGIQVNGPRLESLVLTYVNAISSGDLPCMENAVLALAQIENSAAVQKAIAHYEQQMGQKVQLPTETLQELLDLHRDSEREAIEVFIRSSFKDVDHLFQKELAAQLEKKRDDFCKQNQEASSDRCSALLQVIFSPLEEEVKAGIYSKPGGYRLFVQKLQDLKKKYYEEPRKGIQAEEILQTYLKSKESMTDAILQTDQTLTEKEKEIEVERVKAESAQASAKMLQEMQRKNEQMMEQKERSYQEHLKQLTEKMENDRVQLLKEQERTLALKLQEQEQLLKEGFQKESRIMKNEIQDLQTKMRRRKACTIS'
```

**Functions** - I have done so far:

```
def g4_match(g4,protein):
  N = "NTAG"
  K = "KLQ"
  D = "DE"
  spl_mismatch, mismatch = (0,0)
  for x,y in zip(g4,protein):
    if not (x == 'X' or y == x):
      if(x == 'T' and y in N):
        spl_mismatch+=1
      elif(x == 'L' and y in K):
        spl_mismatch+=1
      elif(x == 'E' and y in D):
        spl_mismatch+=1
      else:
        mismatch+=1
    if mismatch > 0 or spl_mismatch > 2:
        return False
  return True

print g4_match(g4,protein)
```

X can be anything, we want if N is not then check for T, A, G or if K is not then check for L or if D is not then check for E.

our special character is for N == N, T, A, G and for K == K, Q and for D == D, E but if N is there in this case there is no mismatch. I want only two special letter mismatch data or no mismatched like NKXD X can be anything.

**Example**

TLKD here T and L is the special mismatch and ALRD here A and L is special mismatch and TKJE - here T and E is special mismatch and NKID this type data here no special mismatch.

**After Edit getting output**

```
((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (126, 'VYNS'), (165, 'EDSAD'))

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (127, 'YNSI'), (165, 'EDSAD'))

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (128, 'NSIG'), (165, 'EDSAD'))

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (129, 'SIGT'), (165, 'EDSAD'))

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (130, 'IGTI'), (165, 'EDSAD'))
```

In third column, I am not getting expected output. I want only special letter mismatch as per below condition (Only this letters )

Conditions:

1. In the place of if N not there then special mismatch allow N can be `T or A or G`.
2. In the place of K if K not there then special mismatch allow only `L or Q`.
3. In the place of D if D is not there then special mismatch allow `E`

Note: At a time only two condition can be apply.

**Expected Output**

```
((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (126, 'NKID'), (165, 'EDSAD')) - Here no mismatch, 

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (127, 'TQSD'), (165, 'EDSAD'))- here T, Q is the special mismatch

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (128, 'ALDD'), (165, 'EDSAD')) - here A, L is special mismatch

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (129, 'NQGE'), (165, 'EDSAD')) - here Q, E is the special mismatch

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (130, 'GLYD'), (165, 'EDSAD')) - here G, L is the special mismatch
```

I need output like that above expected output

Comment: In what ways is your code not working?  What results do you expect? How do they coompare to what you're getting?

Comment: Dear, I am not getting expected output though this code. I think my logic or something is wrong. Please suggest .. I want to allow two mismatch with special character.  `N = "TAG", K = "LQ", D = "E"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the code: I've tried following your requirement. If you set the protein like 'NKSD', 'TLSD', or 'NQIE', the output will be True. If you set the protein like 'HKSD', or 'TQIE', the output will be False.

```
def g4_match(g4,protein):

    spl_mismatch, mismatch = (0,0)

    for x,y in zip(g4,protein):

        if (x == 'N'):
            if (y == 'N'):
                pass
            elif (y != 'N' and y in 'TAG'):
                spl_mismatch+=1
            else:
                mismatch+=1

        if (x == 'K'):
            if (y == 'K'):
                pass
            elif (y != 'K' and y in 'LQ'):
                spl_mismatch+=1
            else:
                mismatch+=1

        if (x == 'X'):
            pass

        if (x == 'D'):
            if (y == 'D'):
                pass
            elif (y == 'E'):
                spl_mismatch+=1
            else:
                mismatch+=1

    if mismatch > 0 or spl_mismatch > 2:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: Dear, getting `false` as a output. I have edited my full script there I am using this function can you please check once?

Comment: I guess you don't need to check the mismatch again in g4_match(X,Y).  You already checked the mismatch in match(X,Y) Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear, I have edited my question and getting output... I have edited expected output please help me for getting expected output

Comment: Dear, in third column, i want to allow only if `NKXD` is not then in the position of `1. N can be T or A or G` and in the position of `2. K can be L or Q` and in the position of `3. D can be E`. But at a time only two condition can be apply. for example: `1 and 2, or 1 or 3 or 2 or 3`

Comment: Please help me dear, i am trying to get expected result but not getting

Comment: Could you give your expected output sample please. It may be good enough the first 3 or 4 lines.

Comment: Dear I have edited my expected output, In third column, I need output as per expected output. please help